# How to use and prove law of tangents.

Tags: trigonometry

As the title says, I'm having trouble finding any info on the law of tangents. I know how and when to use the law of sines and cosines but not how to use the law of tangents. When is it used and how do you use it?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_tangents#Application for one use.

Comment: Here is the testimony of one who learned the Law of Tangents in high-school: this formula does pretty much what the Law of Cosines does, but is better suited to computation via lookups in a table of logarithms (of trigonometric functions). The problem with LofC is that you need to do multiplications, and then additions, and probably a square root afterwards. Nowadays, with pocket calculators, this is not a problem. The LofT gets the information via multiplications of trig functions only, no additions (though you do need to add and subtract angles, a trivial matter). Forget the LofT!